# ansible playbook переписать в python api

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-playbook

Я первый раз столкнулся с ansible, не ругайтесь)

Есть код на php, который запускает с помощью proc_open команду `ansible-playbook` с дополнительным параметром и определенными переменными окружения

```
$process = proc_open('ansible-playbook -vv -i /path/to/din.py /path/to/new_host.yaml', $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd, $env);
```

Нужно переписать это на python с помощью ansible api

Однако, изучая доки и примеры я не все понял

Вот все, что удалось мне написать **+- с пониманием:**

```
from ansible.vars import VariableManager
from ansible.inventory import Inventory
from ansible.playbook.play import Play
from ansible.executor.playbook_executor import PlaybookExecutor 

env = {...}

playbook_path = '/path/to/new_host.yaml'
variable_manager = VariableManager()

variable_manager.extra_vars = env

loader = DataLoader()

pbex = PlaybookExecutor(playbooks=[playbook_path], variable_manager=variable_manager, loader=loader)
results = pbex.run()
```

Но тут не хватает:

1. `inventory`, который я пока не понял, для чего это и с чем его есть, и нужен ли вообще он тут
2. Указанного в php скрипте файла `/path/to/din.py`

А также я не уверен, что правильно задал переменные, и может еще много чего не хватает

Как правильно составить код?

Comment: Вопрос чисто из интереса: зачем тебе ансибл заворачивать в питон? Какую цель надо достичь в конце?

Comment: @donRumata веб апишку пишу на питоне, которая это будет юзать

Comment: А, ок. В общем inventory - это файл, где содержатся параметры подключения к хосту. Это если в общем случае. Т.е. плейбук, в котором прописан код установки условного мускуля - это отдельный файл, переменные - это тоже отдельный файл, на какие хосты и как подключаться - тоже отдельный файл. При знании абсолютного пути - файл-инвентори может лежать где угодно, главное чтобы он был доступен на чтение.

Comment: https://natenka.gitbooks.io/ansible-dlya-setevih-inzhenerov/content/book/1_ansible_basics/inventory.html

Comment: @donRumata окей, понятно, а что по второму вопросу?

Comment: А, да. `-i` - это как раз указание на файл с инвентори, но судя по тому, что там питоновский скрипт, то речь идёт про https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_inventory.html и https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html

Comment: @donRumata ок, спасибо

Comment: А, есть ещё AWX. Покури его. Может не понадобится писать свой велосипед.

Comment: @donRumata, ок, посмотрю. А для переменных окружения я правильно сделал, что в `varable_manager` засунул их?

Comment: Я в питон не умею, но у ансибла 20+ мест, откуда можно брать переменные. Кури https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html